# 2 IP on same network with different LAN

Tags: mikrotik-routeros

Can I config 2 same IP Address on one network with different LAN

[Configuration on theses picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d6cK.png)

I want to give a detail about my config

[image: with 2 mikrotik and 2 same IP]

I create it because the supplier have make the configuration without discuss with existing team.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? Even if possible, it would cause collisions & no device on the network would be able to identify the correct machine… which is the point of having IP addresses in the first place. I get the feeling this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Well sure you could accomplish this using some creative NAT rules. But are you sure you really absolutely must do it this way?

Answer (score 2):

In your picture, the Mikrotik is just one network.

So two devices cannot have the same IP address.

That is why PC 2 cannot communicate with PC 1 (same IP as PC 1).

When the IP addresses are different, you can communicate.

It is always necessary to keep IP addresses of devices on a simple LAN different. This is quite normal.

If a particular device must have a particular IP for some reason, then the other devices can have different IP addresses to accommodate the setup.

Comment: Thanks alot for your question, now if I use 2 mikrotik, can I to do that?

Comment: If you use 2 Miktrotik routers you will have the same difficulties if you try to use the same subnet (192.168.1.x) and try to connect them - that generally will not work. You need a separate subnet but then the IP addresses are necessarily different.

Comment: i need this case because the supplier have use the existing IP, and i can't change it, so i try to find how to make 2 sampe IP but from 2 mikrotik on one network.

Comment: That is a severe limitation and not really workable. Suppliers have to adapt to IP addressing used.

Comment: If your supplier has equipment that is fixed to a particular IP address, then other devices can have different IP addresses to communicate with it. That is a way to solve your problem.

Comment: The supplier of what has used which existing IP address… where? This really isn't getting any clearer.

Comment: the supplier have make the device with mikrotik IP (192.168.1.) and cant change it (the said)

Comment: now i try to accept 2 same ip on my network, maybe "routes" can solve this problem.

Comment: Then, as I noted, you need to change the other devices that connect

Comment: maybe "routes" can solve this problem.  <--- unlikely if everything has the same subnet  (192.168.1.x)

Comment: So the problem is, that in order to have your traffic go through a router at all, it has to have a destination address that is not on the same network as the sending host. since your host is in 192.168.1.x, it won't send traffic to the router if the destination is 192.168.1.x.  Moreover if station 192.168.1.2 wanted to contact 192.168.1.2 in the other network, it would instead connect to itself. There is no way you can do this with both networks having the same address space, unless you use a technology like NAT to alias the networks as though they were different. that is complicated.

Comment: thank for the answer @FrankThomas for the case, can I use NAT ?

Comment: This SU answer demonstrates the complexity of same subnets, but requires different addresses at each end, so probably too difficult for this purpose above.  https://superuser.com/questions/1010005/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-nat-routing-device-to-have-the-same-subnet-on-both

Comment: if your routers are sophisticated enough, you can theoretically create a pair of nat rules (one SNAT and one DNAT) for each host in both networks on the appropriate router. Most common routers don't allow you to map at the host-level, just the port+host level, so you need serious enterprise hardware to pull it off. then each of your hosts behind router1 or router2 will have an address in the 192.168.101 network. This of course requires that the combined number of devices in all the networks is less than 255. This is seriously a bad idea. don't persue it.